# 14.04 upgrade problem, 3.8.0-31 generic works but not 3.11.0.14; should I do a fresh install?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu

**Original System** 13.10 64bit, dual boot with Windows , 3 x hard drives, Nvidia graphic driver installed;  /home on separate disc from root. All working fine.

**Allowed upgrade to 14.04**, error on restart "error: symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found." As reported by many others.

**Ran Boot-repair from disc**, got grub screen back, but boot into Ubuntu fails after initial screen. Possible to boot into windows.

Rebooting and going into "advanced options for Ubuntu" and choosing recovery mode works but is very slow.
Rebooting into "Ubuntu 3.8.0-31 generic" works, but is not very stable.

If I try to run from the 14.04 live DVD, it hangs with blank screen after choosing "run without installing". The same happens if I try to run from a USB stick made from a separate torrent download of 14.04. Have now tried Xubuntu 14.04 live DVD with the same results

I can run older distros from live CDs and 14.04 disc works on another machine.

I have not yet tried a fresh install and am wary of that because of my /home on a separate drive.

Any suggestions on what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to mention above that my graphics card is 2 x Nvidia Geforce 6800XT cards installed on an SLI motherboard. They have always worked fine before on 13.10 and 13.04.

When I removed the second card, everything booted up normally. So the problem is there. 
Hence my question is now answered.

Answer (score 0):

From now, the error is in Ubuntu and most in the newest Kernel version.
Just use the older, before fixing. I have the same problem with kernel.

Comment: This is not an answer....

Comment: Well after 3 days it's the first attempt at an answer I have received so I'm grateful for that. Thanks @alb3rtano0012 It also coincides with what I'm thinking from reading around.